# Delete workflow task when item is deleted?

Tags: workflow, tasks

I've built a workflow with SPD 2010 that have some custom task process.

Can I ensure the tasks related to the item are removed when the item is deleted ?

[Edit] I just discovered that the tasks are removed when the recycle bin is emptied... not very user friendly since the tasks still are shown in the task list

Answer (score 2):

I would have this set up as a separate "delete" workflow that would remove the associated tasks from the tasks list and then delete the item. Instead of using the default delete button, you would have a workflow that actually performs the delete action and can ensure that all associated artifacts are removed prior to deletion.

Comment: I was thinking to something like this, but this won't covert all ways of deleting (pressing del key, remove the task from the task page itself, etc.). I fear the only way I have is to create an event receiver and do the job from here

Comment: Yes, that is correct, it wouldn't convert the pressing of the delete key. You would either do an event receiver like you plan, or you could hide the delete key and only show your option of deleting.

Comment: @SteveB: I'd highly advise hiding the delete button. It creates havoc and doesn't log changes.  It should be strictly an Admin only button.